# Edited: K means clustering and finding points closest to the centroid

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, k-means

I am trying to apply k means to cluster actors based on the information in the following columns

```
Actors              Movies  TvGuest Awards  Shorts  Special LiveShows
Robert De Niro         111      2     6       0        0       0
Jack Nicholson          70      2     4       0        5       0
Marlon Brando           64      2     5       0        0       28
Denzel Washington       25      2     3      24        0       0
Katharine Hepburn       90      1     2       0        0       0
Humphrey Bogart        105      2     1       0        0       52
Meryl Streep            27      2     2       5        0       0
Daniel Day-Lewis        90      2     1       0       71      22
Sidney Poitier          63      2     3       0        0       0
Clark Gable             34      2     4       0        3       0 
Ingrid Bergman          22      2     2       3        0       4
Tom Hanks               82     11     6      21       11      22
```

```
#began by scaling my data
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

#used an elbow plot to find optimal k value  
sum_of_squared_distances = []
K = range(1,15)
for k in K:
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    model = k_means.fit(X)
    sum_of_squared_distances.append(k_means.inertia_)
plt.plot(K, sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.show()

#found yhat for the calculated k value
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
model = kmeans.fit(X)
yhat = kmeans.predict(X)
```

Unable to figure out create scatter plots by actors.

**EDIT:**
Is there a way to find which actors are closest to centroids if the centroids were also plotted using

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ (The kmeans here refers to Eric's solution below)

plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1],color='purple',marker='*',label='centroid')

Comment: How many dimensions are needed to describe each actor? How many dimensions can you display in order to see something? What do you think are your options? You might benefit from posting your question on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) which will be more suited to this kind of question.

Comment: Not really sure. Thanks for the stack exchange suggestion though

Comment: Please notice that cross-posting [verbatim questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/93156/k-means-clustering-in-pandas-visualization) to multiple SE sites is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu); please choose **one** site only where you think your question would be more appropriate, and delete the post in the other (in fact, as is  it's quite unclear what *exactly* your issue is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### K means clustering in Pandas - Scatter plot

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Actors', 'Movies', 'TvGuest', "Awards", "Shorts"]) 
df.loc[0]             = ["Robert De Niro",     111,     2,    6,      0] 
df.loc[1]             = ["Jack Nicholson",      70,     2,    4,      0] 
df.loc[2]             = ["Marlon Brando",       64,     4,    5,      0] 
df.loc[3]             = ["Denzel Washington",   25,     2,    3,     24] 
df.loc[4]             = ["Katharine Hepburn",   90,     1,    2,      0] 
df.loc[5]             = ["Humphrey Bogart",     105,    2,    1,      0] 
df.loc[6]             = ["Meryl Streep",        27,     3,    2,      5] 
df.loc[7]             = ["Daniel Day-Lewis",    90,     2,    1,      0] 
df.loc[8]             = ["Sidney Poitier",      63,     2,    3,      0] 
df.loc[9]             = ["Clark Gable",         34,     2,    4,      0] 
df.loc[10]            = ["Ingrid Bergman",      22,     5,    2,      3] 

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4) 
y = kmeans.fit_predict(df[['Movies', 'TvGuest', 'Awards']]) 
df['Cluster'] = y 
plt.scatter(df.Movies, df.TvGuest, c=df.Cluster, alpha = 0.6) 
plt.title('K-means Clustering 2 dimensions and 4 clusters') 
plt.show()
```

Shows:

[image]

Notice the data points presented on the 2 dimensional scatterplot is `Movies` and `TvGuest`, however the Kmeans fit was given 3 variables: `Movies`, `TvGuest`, `Awards`.  Imagine there is an additional dimension going into the screen which are used to calculate membership to a cluster.

Source links:

https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/clustering-with-k-means-in-python/

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48693/perform-k-means-clustering-over-multiple-columns

https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-clusters-with-pythons-matplolib-35ae03d87489

Comment: say if I plot centroids as well is there a way to find out which actors are closest to the centroid

Comment: like centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1],color='purple',marker='*',label='centroid')

Comment: Your question is about scatterplot of kmeans broken out by actor. I answered that, if you have a followup question exploring: of `"what if we do something different in a new context, can we do that?"` the answer is yes, and that will have to be a new question.

Comment: Hello again, I have reached my question limit for some reason. (Just asked 2 questions).

Comment: I have modified the question, if that's ok

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate Euclidean distance between points and centroid and find the min distance which indicates closest point to centroids

`dist = numpy.linalg.norm(centroid-point)`